# Memory usage in assembler 8086

Tags: memory, assembly, x86-16

I made a program in assembler 8086 for my class and everything is working just fine.
But beside making working program we have to make it use as low memory as possible. Could you give me some tips in that aspect? What should I write and what should I avoid?

The program is supposed to first print letter A on the screen and then in avery new line two more of letters of next letter in the alphabet, stop at Z and after pressing any key end program. For stopping until key is pressed i'm using: 
mov ah,00h
int 16h
Is it good way to do it?

Comment: This is generally a too vague question and I suspect it will be closed. Your fist step should be to determine a baseline in exactly how much memory your program is using as of your current version. Then check if that number seems reasonable and could it be reduced even more.

Comment: This is such a simple program hat I'm sure your teacher meant that you should use register instructions as much as possible rather than allocating memory to store data.  It should be possible to do this problem with about 2 bytes of data memory.  If the instructor is counting code memory, then you want to look for ways to do things with few, short instructions rather than many and/or long ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of what you want can be done in zero memory (counting only data, not the code itself). In general:

- use registers rather than variables in memory
- do not use push/pop
- do not use subroutines

But to interact with the OS, you need to make BIOS calls and/or OS system calls; these require some memory (typically a small amount of stack space). In your case, you have to:

- output characters to screen
- wait for keypress
- exit back to the OS

However, if you are serious about doing this in **minimal** memory, then there are a few hacks you can use.

### Output characters to screen

On a PC, in traditional text mode, you can write characters straight to video RAM (address B800:0000 and further). This requires zero memory.

### Wait for keypress

The cheapest way is to wait for a change of the BIOS keyboard buffer head (a change of the 16-bit content at address 041A hex). This requires zero memory.
See also: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/60140

### Exit back to the OS

Try a simple `ret`; it is not recommended but it *might* just work in some versions of MS-DOS. An even uglier escape is to jump to `F000:FFF0`, which will reboot the machine. That's guaranteed to work in zero memory.

Answer (score 0):

Use these instructions:

```
INC (Register*) instead of ADD (Register*), 1
DEC (Register*) instead of SUB (Register*), 1
XOR (Register)(same register) instead of MOV (Register), 0  (Doesn't work with variables)
SHR (Register*), 1  instead of  DIV (Register*), 2
SHR (Register*), 2  instead of  DIV (Register*), 4
..
SHL (Register*), 1  instead of  MUL (Register*), 2
..

*Register or variable
```

These optimizations makes the program faster AND the size larger